# Video memory not being written to while handling interrupt that was triggered in user mode

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, interrupt, osdev

Here is the Interrupt handler:

```
 void irsHandler(intData data)
{
    
    char* vm = (char*) 0xb8000;
    vm[0] = 'A';
    
    

}
```

When user code triggers an interrupt by `int` instruction, the handler should display 'A' to the screen. This is not happening any ideas? let me know what other information may be needed.

**UPDATE 1 **

GDT:

```
    gdt_start:
    ;first entry is always null (each entry is 8 bytes or 64 bits)
    dd 0x0 ; 4 byte
    dd 0x0 ; 4 byte

; GDT for code segment. base = 0x00000000, length = 0xfffff
; for flags, refer to os-dev.pdf document, page 36
gdt_code: 
    dw 0xFFFF   ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x0       ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x0       ; seg2ment base, bits 16-23
    db 10011010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11000000b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 24-31

; GDT for data segment. base and length identical to code segment
; some flags changed, again, refer to os-dev.pdf
gdt_data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11000000b
    db 0x0

U_code: 
    dw 0xFFFF    ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x6000    ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x00      ; seg2ment base, bits 16-23
    db 11111010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11000111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x00       ; segment base, bits 24-31

; GDT for data segment. base and length identical to code segment
; some flags changed, again, refer to os-dev.pdf
U_data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x6000
    db 0x00
    db 11110010b
    db 11000111b
    db 0x00
gdt_tss:
    dw TSS_SIZE-1      ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw tss             ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x0             ; segment base, bits 16-23
    db 10001001b       ; access flags (8 bits)
    db 00000000b       ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x0             ; segment base, bits 24-31


gdt_end:

; GDT descriptor
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; size (16 bit), always one less of its true size
    dd gdt_start ; address (32 bit)
```

The function that calls the above c handler

```
    isr_common_stub:
    pusha ;put all common use registers on stak
    
    mov ax, ds ; Lower 16-bits of eax = ds.
    push eax ; save the data segment descriptor
    
    mov ax, 0x10  ; kernel data segment descriptor
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    
    call irsHandler
    ; call c function
   pop eax 
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    popa
    add esp, 8 ; Cleans up the pushed error code and pushed ISR number
    sti
    iret
```

I can see text on the screen. But it is not the int I called. It is int 13 error code 18. It seems to happen when I changes ds to kern segment.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253107/discussion-on-question-by-jacob-knuth-video-memory-not-being-written-to-while-ha); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Which video mode is this? Standard text mode 0?